# Drupal form elements in html table, label (title) rendering

Tags: forms

How to place title/label in other cell of the html  table

I have:

```
function hook_theme() {
  return array(
    'hook_form_table' => array(
      // The renderable element is the form.
      'render element' => 'form',
    ),
  );
}


function hook_form_table_form($form = array(), &$form_state) {

    $form['#theme']= 'hook_form_table';
    $selected_two="";
    $options_second=array("a");
    $form['carmodel'] = array('#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => $options_second,
        '#default_value' => $selected_two,
        '#required' => TRUE, '#title' => t('Car model:'),
        '#validated' => true, 
        '#prefix' => '<div id="replace_carmodel_div">', 
        '#suffix' => '</div>', 
    );

    $options_euro=array("Euro 3,4","Euro 5" );

    $form['euro'] = array('#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => $options_euro,
        '#default_value' => $selected_two,
        '#required' => TRUE, 
         '#title' => t('Euro type:'),
        '#validated' => true, 
     );

    $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Submit'),
    );

  return $form;
}


function theme_hook_form_table(&$variables) {
    $form = $variables['form'];
    $content = '<h2>' . t('Please enter your information below') . '</h2>';
    $content.="<table>";
    $content.="<tr>";
    $content.="<td>";
    $content.=$form['carmodel']['#title'];
    $form['carmodel']["#type"]="";

    $content.="</td>";
    $content.="<td>";
    $form['carmodel']['#title']="";
    $form['carmodel']['#required']="";
    $content .= drupal_render($form['carmodel']);
    $content.="</td>";
    $content.="<td>";
     $content.="hire want euro type  with * and label and all";
    $content.="</td>";
    $content.="<td>";

    $content .= drupal_render($form['euro']);
    $content.="</td>";
    $content.="</tr>";
    $content.="</table>";
  return $content;
}
```

This give me a table but labels is on top:
  [image]
How to render label to put it like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My not nice solution is

```
function drupal_render_label($field){
    $result= "<div class=\"form-item form-type-".$field['#type']." form-item-".$field['#name']."\">";
    $result.= "<label for=\"edit-".$field['#name']."\">".$field['#title'];
    if ($field['#required']==true){
       $result.= "<span class=\"form-required\" title=\"This field is required.\">*</span>";
    }
    $result.="</label>";
    $result.="</div>";
    return $result;
}
```

and then:

```
  $content.="<td>";
  $content.=drupal_render_label($form['carmodel']);
  $content.="</td>";
```

Anyone have sth better?